# import data from source db to target db using flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, sql-insert, insert-update, multiple-databases

I want to fetch data from one source database and insert it into my targeted database using flask SQL alchemy

## Database_connection

```
 app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost/store'
 app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {'store1' : 'mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost/store1'}
 app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```

## Model for first database

```
class Product(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
  description = db.Column(db.String(200))
  price = db.Column(db.Float)
  qty = db.Column(db.Integer)

def __init__(self, name, description, price, qty):
   self.name = name
   self.description = description
   self.price = price
   self.qty = qty
```

## Model for second database

```
class home_products(db.Model):
   __bind_key__= 'store1'
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
   description = db.Column(db.String(200))
   price = db.Column(db.Float)
   qty = db.Column(db.Integer)

def __init__(self, name, description, price, qty):
   self.name = name
   self.description = description
   self.price = price
   self.qty = qty
```

Now how can i fetch data from STORE database and can insert in STORE1 database..?

In SQL command :

```
`INSERT INTO store1.home_products( name, description, price, qty) SELECT name, description, price, qty FROM store.product LIMIT 21, 1; `
```

this is working i want to learn how to implement this command in python flask sqlalchemy, Any help is appreciated :)